# Death formalities done under wrong Gotra

Tags: rituals, death, customs, gotra

I want to know what happens if all the death related formalities ie, Puja, Antim Sanskar, Pind daan, Asthi Visarjan, etc are done unknowingly using wrong gotra. Are there any remedies mentioned in any Hindu texts regarding the same if later the correct gotra is known.

Answer (score 1):

Any Pitru karma done should only given to Pradyumana, Sankarshna, Vasudeva form of lord Narayana on Vishnu pada only. This was demonstrated by Bhisma in Mahabharata, despite knowing that his fathers hand asking the Pinda he gave it vishnu pada only, only vishnu have right to give or take to concerned Pitrus, so gothra doesnt matter.. you have that Prachita mantras like aAbhrama sthamba paryantham deva rishi pitru manava, aAputr Gothraja mrithaaha suthra nishpedanethagam. while doing dharbha visharajanam. .the mantra i gave is from Rigveda i don't have full correct sentence.